# How to execute query on grails using params from gsp?

Tags: sql, hibernate, grails

I need to know how to execute native sql query on grails using params? 
Currently I have some query String which contains some SQL which involved with 3 tables and a UNION.
The idea is to run the query using the given 'params' value from the gsp file call same as done when doing like: DomainClass.list(params)

My call is currently:

> ```
>         def session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()
>         def results = session.createSQLQuery(query).list()
> ```

How can I invoke the execute query using the params ?

Comment: You are running a query that was passed as a part of the request itself?

Comment: Can't get your question.
I'm running a query which has 2 select parts and a union, the total tables amount is 3.

Comment: Yes, but you implied in your question that the query text itself was provided some String which was a part of the request itself. If I understood you correctly, that's a phenomenally bad idea, please don't do this!

Comment: What I'm trying to ask is do you want to do something like this: `sql.executeQuery(params.query)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why wouldn't you use Dynamic Finders or Create Criteria?
I wonder if placing your parameters in a String would expose you to a SQL Injection attack (unnecessary risk).

Dynamic Finders would look like this:

```
Company ACME = Company.findByName(params.MyValue)
Product.findAllByManufacturer(params.MyValue)
Product.findAllByManufacturerAndSalesPriceBetween(params.MyValue, 200, 500)
```

And Criteria looks like this:

```
Transaction.createCriteria().list {
    projections {
        groupProperty 'product'
        sum 'quantity'
    }

    product {
        manufacturer {
            eq 'id', params.MyValue
        }
    }
}
```

These are examples I took from this excellent tutorial:

http://tatiyants.com/how-and-when-to-use-various-gorm-querying-options/

**Seriously, don't place your query parameters in a String.**

Comment: While it's is generally good advice not to concatenate request parameters into SQL queries, in Groovy you can do so safely using string interpolation - they are converted into SQL parameters before being sent to the database, so you are no less safe than doing `User.findByUsername(params.user)`. See chapter *Avoiding SQL injection* in [this documentation article](http://groovy.codehaus.org/gapi/groovy/sql/Sql.html).

Answer (score 0):

See [this](http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/groovy/sql/Sql.html) page for Groovy's SQL reference.

Your simplest option is to inject the `dataSource` bean and generate an SQL object from it, like so:

```
def dataSource

def someMethod() {
    def sql = new Sql(dataSource)
    sql.eachRow("select this, that from table where q = ${params.q} limit ${params.max}") { row ->
        //...do some work here or use a different method on the SQL object
    }
}
```

Groovy will not just do the usual string interpolation but will actually convert your values into parameters that can be passed to the database safely.

Comment: What does 'q' means in your query ?

Comment: It's just an example of using a `params` variable to construct the query (which is what your question was about) - it's up to you to construct the actual query and use your parameters in it.

Comment: Also, how can I paginate the results ?

Comment: Since you're using native SQL it depends on the underlaying database; in Postgresql for example one would write this at the end of the query: `limit ${params.max} offset ${params.offset}`

Comment: is the 'offset' value used to work with the pagination ?

Comment: Yes, in [PostgreSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/queries-limit.html), but I don't even know what database you are using?

Comment: Well for MySQL you would probably use `LIMIT ${params.offset}, ${params.max}` but for specifics you should open another question (I'm not a MySQL expert, either).